# Office.js format HTML in a ContentControl with inline CSS

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I'm inserting a content control like this (ScriptLab example):

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));

var myHtml = '<div style="padding-left:2em; text-indent:-2em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>';

async function run() {
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    var range = context.document.getSelection();
    var cc = range.insertContentControl();
    var ccRange = cc.insertHtml(myHtml, 'Replace');
    await context.sync();
  });
}

async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  }
  catch (error) {
    OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
    OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
  }
}
```

and the expected visual output inside Word is this: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ocplq2la (with the hanging indent). However, the the inline css seems to be ignored and while the text is correctly inserted into the content control, there is no hanging indent like the one from the linked example.

What is the correct way of achieving such styling through Office.js? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug with styling in markup that is passed to insertHtml(). You can usually solve it by including another element of the same type at the end. Please try including `<div></div>` at the end of your markup.

Comment: My markup is now: `<div style="padding-left:2em;text-indent:-2em;"> ... </div><div></div>` -> is this what I needed to try? If it is, unfortunately it didn't do the trick. However, I've discovered that if I put in a style rule like `color:red` next to the padding and the indent, the color does get rendered as red (even if I omit the trailing empty `div`). Could it be that only some CSS rules cause issues/get ignored? Is there something else I can try?

Comment: One more thing you can try: Put the text in a <p> tag and put your style attribute on the <p> element. Then have a empty <p></p> after that. If that doesn't work, I think you can report this as an issue on the following repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. I will report it as an issue on the repo, thanks.